# How do I create a shortcut for my Python script?

Tags: python, shortcut

My problem is pretty simple. I have a script running on loop that I want to be interrupted by a keystroke. I want to be able to interrupt the loop at any times. When I do so, the loop is skipped, so that I can code a report of the work.

Since Python runs a line of code after another, how is that possible?

I tried entering the terminal and pressing ctrl+c whenever I want to interrupt the script, but it is not possible to code a report that way.